# Initial Conditions and Boundary Conditions on a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am currently solving the heat equation in cylindrical coordinates. I have found my general solutions using separation of variables. I was wondering, when do I apply the initial and boundary conditions? Is it when each solution is separated or when I bring them together of the form u(rho,z,phi,t). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It’s been a while since I’ve done heat equations (or any pde for that matter) but I think you apply the boundary conditions to the spacial part only to simplify it then apply your initial conditions to the combined solution.